# Use python lists as a dtype

Tags: pandas

I load csv files of the form

```
fieldA|fieldB|fieldC| 
     X|     Y| 3,4,5|
```

I would like "3,4,5" to be loaded by pandas as a python list, aka `pandas.read_csv(..., dtypes={"fieldC": list},...)`

Right now when calling read_csv, I pass the following converter

```
def _convert_to_list(x, field="pass a field to debug"):
    return list(map(int, x.split(','))) if (x is not None and x != '') else np.nan
```

but I am at a stage where I load/save/reload these dataframes from csv and these lists are a source of bugs. I've upgraded my pandas version to 0.23 because of this extension http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.api.extensions.ExtensionArray.html#pandas.api.extensions.ExtensionArray but I don't know what to make of it. Is this useful for my usecase ? any example I could get inspiration from ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ast.literal_eval

https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval

> ast.literal_eval(node_or_string)
>
> Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python >literal or container display. The string or node provided may only consist of >the following Python literal structures: strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, >lists, dicts, sets, booleans, and None.
>
> This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python values >from untrusted sources without the need to parse the values oneself. It is >not capable of evaluating arbitrarily complex expressions, for example >involving operators or indexing.

Comment: To deal with various cases, I ended up with

def _load_list(x, field="set field to debug"):

    # logger.log(mp.TRACE, "Load field %s list %r" % (field, x))
    if x is None or len(x) == 0:
        return np.nan

    if x[0] != "[":
        x = "[" + x + "]"
    res = ast.literal_eval(x)
    return res

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the `ExtensionArray` facility will help you in terms of input/output of a `DataFrame` containing columns that contain objects that are of type `list`.  There is nothing in the `ExtensionArray` design that assists with input/output issues.

You can find examples of `ExtensionArray` in the subdirectories `decimal` and `json` in the directory `pandas/tests/extension/`.  None of those examples do anything with input/output.